# Word between Overview and Details without resorting to the comical "Detailed Detailed Details"

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word between "Overview" and "Details"?

I tried to search for "intermediate view" but google image's result doesn't make sense.

I also tried to search for synonym of "mesoscopic". But online dictionaries draw a blank.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I want to save "detailed details" level for something else. So I want a word between overview and details.

Comment: Wide-angle, medium-view, and narrow view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an overview gives a short summary of something, and a detailed analysis goes into a great deal of discussion, perhaps what you're looking for is something that is "simply" [**explanatory**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/explanatory):

> serving to explain
>   The explanatory section has as its heading "What the New Tax Changes Mean."

Alternatively (if you need a noun), an [**epexegesis**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epexegesis):

> additional explanation or explanatory matter

These words don't *necessarily* mean "intermediate" (because *in depth explanations* can be given) but they can be taken as such in context. Also, typically, unless you *do* provide an adjective for *explanation*, you don't often mean for it to be detailed.

---

The above is relevant to text.

If you are discussing diagrams or pictures, then this could be represented differently:

- *summary view* (a basic overview of something)
- *functional view* (enough information so that its actual use can be discerned)
- *detailed view* (details beyond just how it's used)

Comment: The whole explanation has many figures. I try to divide the figures into three levels. Currently the figures have either:  1. overview label with red frame, 2. narrow view with yellow frame, and 3. details with green frame. Does "narrow view" sounds odd in this case?

Comment: Hmm. I didn't know "expexegesis" till I look it up. It looks like a complex word. I am not sure if everyone would know/like that one.

Comment: @Rzu I have expanded my answer based on the additional context provided in your comments.

Comment: Thanks! I was literally drawing comics for the intended audience. You gave the answer before I think about the unthinkable. Oh well, maybe I will search the comics online for dialogue next time. :)